# Program to quantify precisely how much lag Dragon NaturallySpeaking has

Tags: speech-recognition

I am looking for a tool to quantify precisely how much recognition lag Dragon NaturallySpeaking has. The recognition lag is the time it takes for Dragon NaturallySpeaking to transcribe what the user said. Obviously I am looking for something more convenient and accurate than a mere manual stopwatch. I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking Professional 12.5 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

My use cases:

1. I have two computers. On each of them Dragon NaturallySpeaking is installed. I would like to compare the recognition lag between the two computers.
2. I want to be able to compare the lag on the same computer right after Windows started and after a while (as over time Windows get slower and slower).
3. I want to analyze how changing the settings of Dragon NaturallySpeaking impacts the recognition lag.